# Admin Custom Shipping Rate

Tags: shipping, admin

I need to ship overseas and use USPS(whose shipping API I am yet to test) and some other carriers that don't have APIs for quoting shipping rates.

There used to be a module that allowed [setting a custom shipping rate from the Admin interface](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/admin-custom-shipping-rate.html).  However, this module isn't available for version 1.7.x.x.

Is there a replacement for this module or some other module that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this extension as a base and develop a new one, however I think that it should work good in 1.7.x.x, also you can check [this post and topic from magentocommerce forum](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/237660/#t343736)

If you need an extension that is 100 compatible with 1.7 you can try paid extension [Admin Based Shipping by WebShopApps](http://www.webshopapps.com/admin-based-shipping.html) that do exactly the same